# Scalability comparison between different DBMSs

Tags: mysql, scaling, database, bigtable

By what factor does the performance (read queries/sec) increase when a machine is added to a cluster of machines running either:

- a Bigtable-like database
- MySQL?

Google's research paper on Bigtable suggests that "near-linear" scaling is achieved can be achieved with Bigtable. [This page here](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/scaleout/zillow.html) featuring MySQL's marketing jargon suggests that MySQL is capable of scaling linearly.

Where is the truth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having built and benchmarked several applications using [VoltDB](http://www.voltdb.com) I consistently measure between 90% and 95% of additional transactional throughput as each new server is added to the cluster.  So if an application is performing 100,000 transaction per second (TPS) on a single server, I measure 190,000 TPS on 2 servers, 280,000 TPS on 3 servers, and so on.  At some point we expect the server to server networking to become a bottleneck but our largest cluster (30 servers) is still above 90%.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't do that many **writes** to the database, `MySQL` may be a good and easy solution, especially if coupled with `memcached` in order to increase the read speed.

OTOH if you data is constantly changing, you should probably look somewhere else:

- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [VoltDB](http://voltdb.com/)
- [Riak](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak)
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)
- [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/)

These systems have been designed to scale linearly with the number of computers added to the system.
A full list is available [here](http://nosql-database.org/).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to find out which one to use, I need detailed statistics on how the systems scale under similar circumstances.

Comment: Here are some interresting benchmarks:

- http://www.brianfrankcooper.net/pubs/ycsb-v4.pdf

- http://blog.medallia.com/2010/05/choosing_a_keyvalue_storage_sy.html

- http://voltdb.com/blog/key-value-benchmarking

The first, from Yahoo, compares the scalability of HBase and Cassandra.

There isn't a standard methodology for testing those systems; each of them has special characteristics that make it more suitable for specific tasks.